# How to force selectrow_array return wrong value?

Tags: perl, dbi

I remember having problem with DBI method `selectrow_array`. When i wasn't tidy enough i got back from it not the value of the column i asked, but count of columns (or something unwanted, i can't recall exactly). Now i try to refactor some code and i want to make sure in every possible place, that i get back only expected value. So i try to avoid surprises and find out which the bad behaviour was. From DBI docs i read that this may be really be problematic situation:

> If called in a scalar context for a statement handle that has more
>   than one column, it is undefined whether the driver will return the
>   value of the first column or the last. So don't do that.  Also, in a
>   scalar context, an "undef" is returned if there are no more rows or if
>   an error occurred. That "undef" can't be distinguished from an "undef"
>   returned because the first field value was NULL.  For these reasons
>   you should exercise some caution if you use "selectrow_array" in a
>   scalar context, or just don't do that.

Still i can't force `selectrow_array` to return anything but value of the `col1` (that's it what i am expecting)

```
my $query = 'SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE id = 112233';

my ( $c ) = ( $dbh->selectrow_array( $query ) );
my $x = ask_from_db();
my $y = $dbh->selectrow_array( $query );
my $z = ( $dbh->selectrow_array( $query ) );
my @A = $dbh->selectrow_array( $query );

say "C: $c"; # C: col1
say "X: $x"; # X: col1
say "Y: $y"; # Y: col1
say "Z: $z"; # Z: col1
say "A: @A"; # A: col1 col2 col3

sub ask_from_db {
  return $dbh->selectrow_array( $query );
}
```

Every way i ask above, gives me fine result. How should i run the query to get wrong result?

wrong result != `col1` value

Comment: I like that question. But I have no idea. I'd have tried the same snippets you have. One way might be the goatse-operator: `my $foo =()= $dbh->selectrow_array($query)`. But who would code that unintentionally, really? Writing this by accident is like accitentally falling on your mp3-player to get it stuck somewhere dark and warm...

Comment: @simbabque: No, unfortunately it was not so poetic, it was simple and clear but took hours to debug to understand that i had problem with context. I was so completly lost :)

Comment: @simbabque, That will assign the number of columns to `$foo`, not the value for the first column.

Comment: @ikegami: yes, that was one of my recall's that i got back number of columns and he proposed a way how it could happened. But like he said, it is gonna hardly happen that someone uses goatse-operator accidentally

Comment: @ikegami the whole point is to make it misbehave.

Comment: @simbabque, Then what I said still applies. That will assign the number of columns to `$foo`. That doesn't make it return something other than the first element.

Comment: @ikegami that is correct, and I didn't say otherwise. But the OP said he 'was sloppy', so I was thinking about ways to sloppily create unwanted behavior. That this does not change the method's return value is very clear to me, but as the OP's tests showed, he needed to be doing something wrong somewhere. I was merely speculating on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference in outcome will be based on the implementation of the driver.

```
wantarray ? @row : $row[0]
```

vs

```
wantarray ? @row : $row[-1]
```

You'd use to use a different driver to get a different outcome. That said, I imagine you'll have a hard time finding a driver that doesn't return the first.

If you want to be sure to get the first, use:

```
( $dbh->selectrow_array( $query ) )[0]
```

Comment: I thought on this, but i was not sure, maybe this one give also some other column on occasion. That's why i wanted to find a way, how to test false value. But now i see, it won't, because it will be already in list context, when slice is coming in.

Comment: No, always the first. This calls `selectrow_array` in list context, which returns all the columns, then picks out the first one. It's called a *list slice*.

Comment: I'm sorry if my comment was vague, that was exactly mine point too.

Answer (score 3):

What the documentation means by "it is undefined whether the driver will return the value of the first column or the last" is that the column returned is defined by the database driver and not `DBI`.

So the Postgres driver may decide to always return the first column whereas the mysql driver may always return the last column, or the column returned might depend on the query.

So don't call `selectrow_array` is scalar context - always call it in list context:

```
my @row = $sth->selectrow_array($query)
```

and you'll avoid all of the issues that the documentation mentions.

Comment: It is my fault, i forgot to define my goal, why i want to return it in scalar context! I wanted to avoid intermediate variables in simple subroutines, so i could directly return values from DB call. When i can't be sure about getting right value, i must use assigning to `@row`.